# Requests scraping mulitple elements from a list

Tags: python, python-requests

I am having an issue scraping all 5 PlayerId's and duration from this liveData feed. By listing the `[0]` element i am able to get 1 of the 5 players. I would like to get all 5 at the same time under the same Header `HomePlayer` and `AwayPlayer` also `HomeDuration` and `AwayDuration`. I tried copying `HomePlayer` Mulitple times and changing the `[0]` to `[1]` but it will only scrape on of them not both which makes sense.

```
import requests
import csv

req = requests.get('https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/game/2017020397/feed/live?site=en_nhl')
data = req.json()

my_data =[]

team_home, team_away = data['liveData']['boxscore']['teams']['home'], data['liveData']['boxscore']['teams']['away']

HomePlayer = team_home['onIcePlus'][0]['playerId']
AwayPlayer = team_away['onIcePlus'][0]['playerId']
HomeDuration = team_home['onIcePlus'][0]['shiftDuration']
AwayDuration = team_away['onIcePlus'][0]['shiftDuration']

my_data.append([HomePlayer, HomeDuration, AwayPlayer, AwayDuration])

headers = ["HomePlayer", "HomeDuration", "AwayPlayer", "AwayDuration"]

with open("NHL_2017020397_PbP_Shift.csv", "a", newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    writer.writerows(my_data)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only accessing data for one player. So it is only writing that one player's data.

If you are sure that 5 records will be returned from the API then add a `for` block inside the `CSV` block to access each Player's data using the index on the array and writing them down one by one.

Check the code below. I moved the whole data logic into the `CSV` block to loop through the list of players and write them down.

While this not a very Python way of doing it, you should do rest of the looking up to improve the code quality.

```
import requests
import csv

req = requests.get('https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/game/2017020397/feed/live?site=en_nhl')
data = req.json()

team_home, team_away = data['liveData']['boxscore']['teams']['home'], data['liveData']['boxscore']['teams']['away']

headers = ["HomePlayer", "HomeDuration", "AwayPlayer", "AwayDuration"]

with open("/Users/kaybus/Desktop/NHL_2017020397_PbP_Shift.csv", "a", newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(headers)

    for i in range(5):
        HomePlayer = team_home['onIcePlus'][i]['playerId']
        AwayPlayer = team_away['onIcePlus'][i]['playerId']
        HomeDuration = team_home['onIcePlus'][i]['shiftDuration']
        AwayDuration = team_away['onIcePlus'][i]['shiftDuration']
        my_data =[]

        my_data.append([HomePlayer, HomeDuration, AwayPlayer, AwayDuration])
        writer.writerows(my_data)
```

Comment: no need to close the file explicitly when opened using `with`

Comment: Frankly, I am not that of a hardcode Python programmer. I just corrected the logic to get OP going. Please feel free to edit and add any useful comments to the answer. Thanks for the edit btw!

Comment: Thank you! Does the [i] stand for item? is there a list i could reference somewhere for more abbreviations?

Comment: It's a plain array which contains elements. Suppose `arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` you can access each element using arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3] and so on. You can read up about arrays in any programming language.